# Non uniqueness of extenstions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

$\textbf{Problem}$

I have the sets S={1,2,3,4} and F={{1,2},{3,4}} and the measure $\mu:F\rightarrow [0,\infty]$ defined by $\mu({1,2})=\mu({2,3})=\dfrac{1}{2}$. Now I need to find two different extensions of $\mu$ to $\sigma (F)=P(S)$ where P(S) is the power set of S.

$\textbf{What I tried}$

I know that both extended measures $\overline\mu_1,\overline\mu_2$ should have that $\overline\mu(\{1,2\})=\overline\mu(\{3,4\})=\dfrac{1}{2}, \overline\mu(\{1,2,3,4\})=1$ and $\overline\mu(\emptyset)=0$. But I do not know how to proceed from this and what I need to with $\sigma (F)=P(S)$. I thought $\sigma (F)=\{\emptyset, \{1,2\}, \{3,4\}, \{1,2,3,4\}\}\neq P(S)$?!

Can someone help me with this

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You are working at too abstract a level. Experiment with numerical values for the probability of each of the four singletons to find two different assignments that make each of the two required doubletons have probability $1/2$.

Comment: Ah thank you, I now see how I can set up the extended measures, but still don't get what is meant by $\sigma(F)=P(S)$

Comment: I think it means the sigma field is the set of all subsets of $S$.

Comment: Yeah that is right, but I don't see why the sigma field is the set of all subsets of S, since $\sigma(F)$ is the smallest sigma algebra which contains F. Can you show for example why $\{1,2,3\}\in\sigma(F)$.

Comment: The assertion is that $\sigma(F)$ is supposed to grow to include all the subsets of $S$. So you are to extend $\mu$ as defined on just the sets you're given to all of the power set of $S$.